# Will YouTube Android Player API use an account from YouTube app?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

As stated in the [Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/):

> Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.

Does it mean that YouTube Player API will use an account from the YouTube app? 
And the most interesting thing for me: if user will be signed in with YouTube Red account in the YouTube app, will Player API use capabilities (absence of ads) of this account too?

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher)
>   to use the API.

This simply means that the YouTube Player API shares structural components with the YouTube app.